# What is the word class of "studying" in "studying hard is the key to success"?

Tags: verbs, nouns, parts-of-speech, gerunds

This has caused some debate amongst myself and some others. The two claims are that in "studying hard is the key to success", that "studying" is either (1) a noun (gerund) or (2) a verb. In this particular context, is "studying" a gerund?

Comment: The verb there is *is*

Comment: The term 'gerund' is considered unhelpful by many, though this would have been the traditional classification here. On Quirk et al's noun ... verb gradience model, it's over 50% nouny ('Studying hard' being the subject) with quite a lot of verbiness (semantically, hard work involved; syntactically, modified by an adverb). But lumping/splitting is a battlefield.

Comment: Notice that the phrase "studying hard" is the subject of the sentence. So it's acting like a noun.